# PHPStorm not seeing changes after renaming files

Tags: git, phpstorm

In my PHPStorm project, I renamed some files using `Refactor > Rename`. However, now when I make changes to the files PHPStorm does not immediately see the changes, and thus does not upload the newly modified files to my server. The project is tracked using a local git repository, and uploads automatically after a commit.

If I open up the GitHub Windows application, I can see the modified files. What's interesting is after opening up the GitHub app, PHPStorm will tell me the files have been renamed, but the rename happened many commits ago!

The modified files do show up dark blue on the project explorer, and the files in question are not in my `.gitignore`.

Comment: Will `File | Synchronize` (or 3rd button on main toolbar) help here at all?

Comment: @LazyOne This works! However, do you think there is a way to remove this intermediate step?

Comment: AFAIK "Refactor | Rename" should take care of this step automatically (it should notify internal virtual file system about file renaming). I'm not using any VCS myself and cannot advice if it's normal (existing bug) or your environment specific thing. I'd suggest 1) check Issue Tracker for existing tickets that would match your issue (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and 2) contact JB support about it (support@jetbains.com)

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks again for the response, I actually found that `Git > Revert` and then trying `Refactor > Rename` again fixed this issue. A bug was filed here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug when renaming a file with only a letter case change: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-53175

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to rename/move files by git rather than by PHPStorm or other IDE

```
'git mv' <options>... <args>...
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv